# How to search value from MySQL table as per multiple column value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search table's for a mobile, first name or last name and return the row in the table using PHP and MySQL. My tables are below.

db_user:

```
id           mobile        info_id             status    
1            9937229870    12                  1   
2            1234567892    13                  1
3            2123212324    14                  1
```

db_user_info:

```
info_id      fname         email               lname    
  12         Jay           as@gmail.com        Roy   
  13         Jarin         aw@gmail.com        Raot        
  14         Stoks         aq@gmail.com        Dravid
```

db_skill:

```
skill_id     info_id       category
1            13            cat1
2            14            cat2
3            15            cat3
```

For example if a user has the name Jay Roy and their email is aw@gmail.com and the mobile is 2123212324 then it would return:

db_user_info:

```
info_id      fname         email               lname    
12           Jay           as@gmail.com        Roy   
13           Jarin         aw@gmail.com        Raot
```

db_user:

```
id           mobile        info_id             status
3            2123212324    14                  1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what you need is a `JOIN`, 3 `OR LIKE` clauses, and maybe a `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Jeff: I need `like`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this hop it will help you

```
$flname = explode(" ",$name);
$fname=  $flname[0];
$lname = isset($flname[1]) ?  $flname[1] : $flname[0];

select * from db_user du, db_user_info dui, db_skill ds where du.info_id = dui.info_id AND du.info_id = ds.info_id AND (du.mobile like '%$mobile%' OR dui.fname like '%$fname%' OR dui.lname like '%$lname%' OR dui.email like '%$email%');
```

EDIT:
Added different columns and value for name search

Comment: I tested it can not search my name but can search by other two.

Comment: yeah right for that either I or you have to distinguish your value into two cloums

Comment: No,same result is coming it can not search by name.

Comment: try to print value of variable $fname and $lname what you getting

Comment: sorry it was my fault its working as per expected.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
  select a.*,b.*,c.* from db_user as  a inner join db_user_info b on a.info_id =b.info_id inner join db_skill c on b.info_id = c.info_id where a.mobile = "'.$usermobile.'" and b.email = "'.$useremail.'" and CONCAT(b.fname,' ',b.lname) = "'.$username.'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    db_user.*, 
    db_user_info.*, 
    db_skill.*
FROM 
    db_user, 
    db_user_info, 
    db_skill
WHERE 
    db_user_info.info_id = db_user.info_id
AND
    db_user_info.info_id = db_skill.info_id
AND (
        concat_ws(' ', db_user_info.fname, db_user_info.lname) like '%Jay Roy%'
    OR      
        db_user_info.email = 'aw@gmail.com'
    OR
        db_user_info.mobile = '2123212324'

    )
```

Comment: Here i need to search data and should use `LIke` keyword not where.

Comment: Have you tried this in your sql query? and For name I already user LIKE if you want same for email and mobile then replace = with like, simple!

Comment: I changed and tested your code its searcing but for concatenation of name  its not searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "(SELECT content, title, 'msg' as type FROM db_user WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'topic' as type FROM db_user_info WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
           UNION
           (SELECT content, title, 'comment' as type FROM db_skill WHERE content LIKE '%" . 
           $keyword . "%' OR title LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')";

mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

=> You can try to search data using this format